# How to assign key to component in the case when we always have an array of size one

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs component and I use it as following:

```
   render() {
    var returnVar="";
            returnVar= <div>
                {
                    this.props.channels.preferedChannelsList.map(function (item, i) {
                        return ( <StoryBoard
                            key={this.props.match.params.search === "search"?Math.random():"storyBoard-" + i + "-" + item.name.replace("&","and").replace("`","").replace("'","")}
                         ></StoryBoard>)
                    }.bind(this))

            </div>;
        </div>

    return (
        returnVar

    );
  }
}
```

As you see I have to choose key for my component storyboard differently based on the path. The reason is in the case of search I always have an array of size 1 and if I choose i as the index when I do different searches the storyboard component does not render since it does not understand the component has been changed based on the key. I am not sure if assigning random value is a good approach though. Is there any better way of assigning key in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I am not sure if assigning random value is a good approach though?**
>
> Keys should be stable, predictable, and unique. Unstable keys (like those produced by Math.random()) will cause many component instances and DOM nodes to be unnecessarily recreated, which can cause performance degradation and lost state in child components.

For more [`React#Keys`](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)

Its better to use some hash value from `item`

```
this.props.channels.preferedChannelsList.map(function (item, i) {
                        return ( <StoryBoard
                            key={item.someKeyWithUniqueData}
                         ></StoryBoard>)
                    }.bind(this))
```